# C program to calculate simple interest payments

Tags: c

Im trying to write this code for school, and im absoultly stuck on what im doing wrong, if anyone could just point me in the right direction, that would be helpful. Trying to learn as much as i can.
My program doesnt calculate out, how much is owed at the end of each month, after subtrackting the payment, and then adding the interest.
IT just displays the same value.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
float loan;
float interest;
int n;
float outstanding;
float outstanding2;
float princeable;
float payment;


printf("\nEnter the amount of the loan: \n ");
scanf("%f" , &loan);
printf("\nEnter monthly interest percentage\n ");
scanf("%f" , &interest);
printf("\nEnter monthly payments: \n ");
scanf("%f" , &payment);
printf("\nEnter number of monthly Payments: \n ");
scanf("%i" , &n);


while (n >= 0) {
    outstanding = (loan - payment);
    outstanding = (outstanding * (1 + (interest/100)));


    printf("\Outstanding Balance after %i =%.2f\n\n", n, outstanding);
    n--;
}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: What's the question? (That is, what is the problem you're having?)

Comment: What's the problem? Error compiling? Error running it? Does not calculate correctly?

Comment: My guess is, the "outstanding balance" never changes. It is the same for each iteration.

Comment: @BenvanGompel - Unless it's a US Mortgage from 6 years ago - in which case the "outstanding balance" increases with each iteration.

Comment: The question _is_ present, but it's more of a statement in the beginning. @BenvanGompel is correct.

Comment: Marked up as the question is clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each iteration, you should calculate `outstanding` based on its previous value, and not on the initial loan's value, because you also pay interest for interest.

```
outstanding = loan;
while (n > 0) {
    outstanding = (outstanding - payment);
    outstanding = (outstanding * (1 + (interest/100)));

    printf("\Outstanding Balance after %i =%.2f\n\n", n, outstanding);
    n--;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
outstanding = (loan - payment);
```

within the loop is incorrect since it starts with the initial `loan` value each time. It should be:

```
outstanding = (outstanding - payment);
```

You'll also have to set `outstanding` to `loan` before entering the loop.

On top of that, you have one too many loop iterations, and an illegal escape sequence `\O` in your `printf` string.